# A question about conjugate elements of group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. $a,b,x,y$ are elements of $G$.If $ab=ba$, $xy=yx$, $a$ is conjugate to $x$ and $b$ is conjugate to $y$ and $(o(a),o(b))=1$, then can we get $ab$ is conjugate to $xy$? I can’t give a contradictory example.

Comment: Try to look for a counterexample with $a = x$. Look for elements of $C_G(x)$ which are conjugate in $G$ but not in $C_G(x)$.

Comment: I can concoct a counterexample with $x=a$ of order $72$ as a semidirect product of $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_3$ by $C_2$, where the acting $C_2$ interchanges the two $C_2$ factors and the two $C_3$ factors, but perhaps there are smaller examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Dihedral groups give some examples with $x = a$ in the cyclic subgroup of index $2$. The smallest example has order $24$.

Comment: @spin yes, that's a nice example! This seems a reasonable question, and I don't think that it should have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

The question was basically answered in the comments, so I will expand them to an answer.

If $a$ is conjugate to $x$, say $a^g = x$, then $(ab)^g = a^g b^g = b^g a^g$. So by replacing $a$ with $a^g$, we may assume that $a =x$.

So the question is the following. Suppose that $xy = yx$ and $xy' = y'x$, where $y$ and $y'$ are conjugate in $G$, and $\gcd(o(x), (y)) = 1$. Must $xy$ and $xy'$ be conjugate in $G$?

Well, in this situation $xy$ and $xy'$ are conjugate if and only if $y,y'$ are conjugate in $C_G(x)$. (I leave the proof of this fact to the reader of this answer.)

So to find a counterexample, look for $y,y' \in C_G(x)$ which are conjugate in $G$ but not in $C_G(x)$. There are many such examples. You can find some in a suitable dihedral group $G$, take $x$ to be an element in the cyclic subgroup of index $2$ in $G$.

Comment: In the terminology of fusion, the question is whether $C_G(x)$ always "controls fusion" (i.e. no two conjugacy classes of $C_G(x)$ are fused in $G$). This type of property is a bit special, and usually you would not expect it to hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Following your answer, I succeed in finding a counterexample. But I still have a question with your answer. You wrote that 'in this situation xy and xy′ are conjugate if and only if y,y′ are conjugate in CG(x)'. It is trivial  to prove if y,y′ are conjugate in CG(x), then xy and xy′ are conjugate. But the other side of the proof is not obvious.

Comment: For the other direction you will need to use the fact that $\gcd(o(x), o(y)) = 1$.

Comment: Supposing that $(xy)^g=xy'$ , I can only get the result  $gyg^{-1} \in C_G(x)$. And from $(o(x),o(y))=1$ , then $\exists u,v\in Z \,\,s.t.\,uo(x)+vo(y)=1$ and $o(xy)=o(x)o(y)$. So why $y$ and $y'$ are conjugate in $C_G(x)$.

Comment: @ShabbyGrey: If $(xy)^g = xy'$, then $x^gy^g = xy'$. Now $x^g$ and $y^g$ commute, so raising both sides to $o(y)$ power we get $(x^g)^{o(y)} = x^{o(y)}$. Then use $\gcd(o(x), o(y)) = 1$ and Bezout to conclude $x^g = x$, i.e. $g \in C_G(x)$.